# CSS: png image lost it's quality and resolution on smaller screens

Tags: css, frontend

I've got a png text-image on 850x40px resolution. When I test my website on smaller resolutions (384x640px) the quality of this image is completely spoiled like on the screen below. Why something like this happen and how can i fix it?

[image]

Comment: Show your code and try to create a jsfiddle verion.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is may be being scaled in a wrong ratio on small screens. Try to apply an img responsiveness `css` trick... so following is Bootstrap's `.img-responsive` class:

```
.img-responsive {
   max-width: 100%; 
   display:block; 
   height: auto;
}
```

So you can apply this class to you image or set it globally declaring you css class selector as `img { ... }`